# Could not connect to Sybase Central DB via Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, sybase, laravel-5.7

I just installed Laravel 5.7 on my windows 7 machine and I want to use Sybase Central (v6.1) as my database but I can not seem to figure out how to connect to it.

I did a lot of google search but there is not much information out there when it comes to Sybase. This is what I'm trying but it does not work.

```
'connections' => [
    'sybase' => [
        'driver'   => 'odbc',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'host-name'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 'port-number'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db-name'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ]
]
```

The error I get

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unsupported driver [odbc] in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php:283 Stack trace: #0
```

Does Laravel support Sybase or not?

Comment: you need a different driver. It does not come out of the package. try laravel-sqlanywhere

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Laravel doesn't look to support `odbc`, but there seems to be a package you can install to support it available at [ODBC integration for Laravel Framework.](https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-odbc)

Simply follow the installation and usage guides on the page, and you should be able to use `"driver" => "odbc"` without issue.

From terminal run

```
composer require abram/laravel-odbc
```

Then configure the following files:

config/database.php

```
"connections" => [
    "sybase" => [
        "driver" => "odbc",
        ...
    ]
]
```

config/app.php

```
"providers" => [
  ...
  Abram\Odbc\ODBCServiceProvider::class
]
```